# Apache 403 Forbidden error on Windows 10, i tried everything

Tags: php, apache

I'm learning php. Everything was going ok until one day i got this error. I'm using a folder with exercises which is located in c/xampp/htdocs.
I tried everything like granting access to ALL, making a new virtual host, reinstalling and so on. Also checked the apache logs this is what i found

[core:error] [pid 14228:tid 1856] (20023)The given path was above the root path

[This is the error i get in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTynO.png)

Edit: the whole xampp folder has read-only permission but when i change it nothing happens and it resets them back to read-only.

Comment: How is the path used in the browser that gives that error?

Comment: http://localhost/c:/xampp/htdocs/php-crash-course-2020-master

Comment: The path should should follow how it appears in htdocs, after the localhost. Something like: `localhost/php-crash-course-2020-master`. The `localhost` portion of the path is already configured to start from `c:\xampp\htdocs` as the basis.

Comment: Yet i still get the same error

Comment: Well, you've mentioned having changed configuration, so I don't know where you stand. If you simply do: `http://localhost/` should at least show (assuming the index.php file is present in htdocs) the default apache info that typically appears when first installed with apache running.

Comment: The xampp dashboard actually works on 'localhost/' while everything else doesnt. Weird issue that i cant fix, its been 2 days.

Comment: Try a basic test: 1. Add a new folder under htdocs, name it `test`. 2. Then cd to test, and create a very basic php file, named `index.php`. Inside this file, the only contents should be: `<?php phpinfo();`. Save that and then 3. try `http://localhost/test/`. If it works, a graphical output of php information should appear. If it doesn't work then 4. try the full path: `http://localhost/test/index.php`, but if that _still_ doesn't work, then 5. try a new fresh install since the state of the configuration is not known.

Comment: It works! Does this mean that the 'crash course' folder that is corrupt/private? If so, should i just make the files myself? Anyway, i really really apreciate your time and effort Paul!

Comment: Not knowing the contents of the `crash course` folder, I'm not sure. Is there an index.php file in the `php-crash-course-2020-master` folder, or are there other sub-directories? ... I'm not sure without other details. If that crash course was an extracted file, there might be a sub-folder of the same name to which you'd have to specify the directory twice to get to the expected level.

Comment: Apparently something was wrong with the crash course folder! Issue fixed by creating the folders and files myself! Thank you so much for the help Paul!

Comment: Great! ... glad the basic test (assuming to step 3?) was all that was needed. Knowing that the dashboard was ok made me suspect the `crash course` may have been suspect. So, at least you have a way to troubleshoot going forward, but glad you got it working without having to reinstall anything!